# Can we use Elixir plugins with EMQ X Broker?

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, rebar3, emq

EMQ X has the provision to build with Elixir based plugins as per https://github.com/emqx/emqx-rel#build-with-elixir-plugins. But, it's not compiling and throwing the following error

```
➜ make      
ln -snf _build/emqx/lib ./_checkouts
EMQX_DESC="EMQ X Broker" /Users/XXXXX/Programs/emqx-rel/rebar3 as emqx release
===> Compiling rebar_mix
===> Compiling _build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix_builder.erl failed
_build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix_builder.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'mod_vsn'

===> Plugin rebar_mix not available. It will not be used.
===> Compiling rebar3_elixir_compile
===> Compiling _build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix_hook.erl failed
_build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix_hook.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'mod_vsn'

===> Plugin {rebar3_elixir_compile,
                       {git,
                           "https://github.com/barrel-db/rebar3_elixir_compile.git",
                           {branch,"master"}}} not available. It will not be used.
===> Compiling relup_helper
===> Compiling _build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix_elixir_finder_hook.erl failed
_build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix_elixir_finder_hook.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'mod_vsn'

===> Plugin {relup_helper,{git,"https://github.com/emqx/relup_helper",
                                      {branch,"master"}}} not available. It will not be used.
===> Compiling pc
===> Compiling _build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix.erl failed
_build/default/plugins/rebar_mix/src/rebar_mix.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'mod_vsn'

===> Plugin {pc,{git,"https://github.com/emqx/port_compiler.git",
                            {tag,"v1.11.1"}}} not available. It will not be used.
===> Compiling rebar3_run
===> Plugin {rebar3_run,{git,"https://github.com/emqx/rebar3_run",
                                    {tag,"0.2.3"}}} not available. It will not be used.
and rebar.config diff from the latest emqx-rel's master

diff --git a/rebar.config b/rebar.config
index 81fd886..571b07b 100644
--- a/rebar.config
+++ b/rebar.config
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 %% NOTE: Order of the deps matters!
-{elixir_deps, []}.
+{elixir_deps, [
+       {emq_elixir_plugin, {git, "git@github.com:emqx/emqx-elixir-plugin.git", {branch, "master"}}}
+]}.
 
 {deps,
  [emqx,
@@ -113,11 +115,14 @@
     {template,"{{output_dir}}/../../lib/emqx/etc/{{vm_args_file}}","etc/vm.args"},
     {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/emqx/etc/certs","etc/"},
     {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/cuttlefish/cuttlefish","bin/"},
-    {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/cuttlefish/cuttlefish","bin/cuttlefish-{{rel_vsn}}"}
+    {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/cuttlefish/cuttlefish","bin/cuttlefish-{{rel_vsn}}",
+       {copy, "{{base_dir}}/consolidated", "releases/{{rel_vsn}}/consolidated"}}
    ]}
  ]}.
 
-{elixir_relx_apps, []}.
+{elixir_relx_apps, [
+       {emq_elixir_plugin, load}
+]}.
 
 {edge_relx_apps, []}.
```

and `rebar.config` diff from the latest `emqx-rel`'s `master`

```
diff --git a/rebar.config b/rebar.config
index 81fd886..571b07b 100644
--- a/rebar.config
+++ b/rebar.config
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 %% NOTE: Order of the deps matters!
-{elixir_deps, []}.
+{elixir_deps, [
+       {emq_elixir_plugin, {git, "git@github.com:emqx/emqx-elixir-plugin.git", {branch, "master"}}}
+]}.
 
 {deps,
  [emqx,
@@ -113,11 +115,14 @@
     {template,"{{output_dir}}/../../lib/emqx/etc/{{vm_args_file}}","etc/vm.args"},
     {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/emqx/etc/certs","etc/"},
     {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/cuttlefish/cuttlefish","bin/"},
-    {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/cuttlefish/cuttlefish","bin/cuttlefish-{{rel_vsn}}"}
+    {copy, "{{output_dir}}/../../lib/cuttlefish/cuttlefish","bin/cuttlefish-{{rel_vsn}}",
+       {copy, "{{base_dir}}/consolidated", "releases/{{rel_vsn}}/consolidated"}}
    ]}
  ]}.
 
-{elixir_relx_apps, []}.
+{elixir_relx_apps, [
+       {emq_elixir_plugin, load}
+]}.
 
 {edge_relx_apps, []}.
```

```
➜ erl   
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1.7] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V11.1.7  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

```
➜ rebar3 -v
rebar 3.14.3 on Erlang/OTP 23 Erts 11.1.7
```

```
➜ iex -v    
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1.7] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

IEx 1.11.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 23)
```